# Cannot create topics in service bus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I created a service bus account with `Basic` tier and tried to create a `Topic` but I saw that it was not possible due to the `Basic` tier. So I deleted this service bus and created another one with the same name, but this time with the tier as `Standard`. Now when I try to create a topic I get the message:

> SubCode=40000. Cannot operate on type Topic because the namespace 'XXXX' is using 'Basic' tier.

But it´s `Standard` as you can see on the image:

[image: sb]

Answer (score 1):

> There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things.
>
> -- Phil Karlton

Service Bus is not an exception. Your best bet at this point is to contact Azure support directly or via Twitter.